# Can not call method in Backgroundworker

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

My code is as below:

```
public static void methodA()
{
    var bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bgw.DoWork += worker_Dowork;
    bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
}

static void worker_Dowork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //I call this method from another class
    if (Utilities.isInternet())
    {

    }
}

static void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

When `worker_Dowork` is running, method `Utilities.isInternet()` is not getting called or running.

How do I fix it?

Comment: What do you meant by cannot call? Runtime exception? Compiler error? Or what?

Answer (score 1):

There are may be some illegal crossthread call, because `BackgroundWorker` invokes `worker_Dowork` method in another thread. Some times exceptions like this are not thrown, they are catched by `BackgroundWorker` class. You can make your check in main thread, like this:

```
public static void methodA()
{
    var bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bgw.DoWork += worker_Dowork;
    bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;

    if (Utilities.isInternet())
    {
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}

static void worker_Dowork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // Your code goes here
}

static void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{

}
```